# Pause and Resume QThread

Tags: multithreading, pyqt, python-multithreading, qthread

I am using Python, PyQt5, QThread.

I have a GUI, which displays pictures and changes them with a "Continue" Button.

What I want to reach:
In another tab I have a Button "Start".

When the "start" button is pressed, let's say 8 pictures should be preprocessed (changed in size an saved in a dict).
With every click on "continue", a picture should be shown another new picture should be preprocessed and the first picture (QPixmap object) should be deleted.

So first run would be:
picture 1-8 preprocessed
picture 1 displayed

Second run:
picture 9 preprocessed
picture 2 displayed

To not freeze the GUI, I will need a Thread here. My idea is to stop this thread after 8 pictures at the first run and then after every preprocessed picture but to never destroy the process.

How would you realize this thread pause?

The main problem with this will be if someone clicks too fast on "continue" (example: picture 9 is still preprocessing but its tried to already start preprocessing of picture 10, but i just want to add picture 10 to the pictures to be preprocessed and not to stop something...)

Can you help me with this?

Comment: I wouldn't care about pausing and resuming. Instead use a python Queue to "push" the images that are to e processed, in the thread function use a while loop that starts with a `queue.get()` that waits for new queued images and eventually processes them. Note that the signal that emits the image should be able to both store the new image in the dictionary *and* show it if it's the currently requested image.

Comment: My input is a very very long list of files, i can not just queue them all and save them, only a part of them and wait for the "continue" button then. How would you suggest to wait after a few images have been processed? Sorry maybe you already wrote the answer, I am not very familiar with Queues... 

Basically, before the queue starts i already know all the picture paths to be processed and I dont want to save all that date (about 1 terrabyte) into a dict..

Comment: The queue will be only used in the thread, so you have to put only the first 8 items at the beginning, then add the others only when needed (like in your example, add the ninth picture when the second is loaded). I suggest you to take a look at the documentation and look for some tutorials about the topic to understand the concept: it's basically a "list" of items that are pop out when required, with the difference that they are completely thread safe.

Comment: One question, though: are you completely sure that the image processing will **always** go in the same order (always show the next image, and *never* allow displaying the previous one)? And is it always sequential, or are you going to add support for skipping? Because these three ways of accessing the "queue" require very different approaches.

Comment: It was the idea to add the "show previous" option as well as skipping yes. Thats why I wanted to load kind of a sector of images before and after a marker on the current image... but I see your point with the queues, there would be some simplifications by using the "only forward" way with queues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, you don't usually need to "pause" the thread, but to properly *queue* the processing based on the needed preload count. The thread will then "pause" itself, but only because it's waiting for new objects to process.

Assuming that the processing is **always** sequential and in one direction (no going back to the previous image), a possible solution is to always queue the `n + preload-count` item every time a new image is shown.

```
from queue import Queue
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Loader(QThread):
    imageReady = pyqtSignal(int, QImage)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = Queue()

    def run(self):
        self.keepRunning = True
        while self.keepRunning:
            index, path = self.queue.get()
            image = QImage(path)
            # simulate long processing
            self.msleep(image.width() + image.height())
            result = image.scaled(600, 600, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            self.imageReady.emit(index, result)

    def process(self, index, path):
        self.queue.put((index, path))

    def stop(self):
        self.keepRunning = False
        self.wait()


class LinearImageProcess(QWidget):
    cacheSize = 10
    currentIndex = -1
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.startButton = QPushButton('Start')
        self.continueButton = QPushButton('Continue', enabled=False)
        self.view = QLabel()
        self.view.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.view.setFixedSize(600, 600)
        layout.addWidget(self.startButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.continueButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)

        self.fileList = tuple(enumerate(
            QDir(QDir.tempPath()).entryList(['*.jpg', '*.png'])))
        self.cache = []
        self.loader = Loader()
        self.loader.start()
        self.loader.imageReady.connect(self.imageReady)

        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.continueButton.clicked.connect(self.showNext)

    def start(self):
        self.startButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.currentIndex = 0
        for i, file in self.fileList[:self.cacheSize]:
            self.loader.process(i, file)

    def showNext(self):
        if self.cache:
            self.view.setPixmap(self.cache.pop(0))
        else:
            self.continueButton.setEnabled(False)
        nextIndex = self.currentIndex + 1
        if nextIndex < len(self.fileList):
            self.currentIndex = nextIndex
        nextProcess = self.currentIndex + self.cacheSize
        if nextProcess < len(self.fileList):
            self.loader.process(*self.fileList[nextProcess])

    def imageReady(self, index, image):
        pm = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        if self.currentIndex == index:
            self.view.setPixmap(pm)
            self.continueButton.setEnabled(self.currentIndex < len(self.fileList))
        else:
            self.cache.append(pm)
            self.continueButton.setEnabled(True)
        if self.continueButton.isEnabled():
            self.continueButton.setFocus()


app = QApplication([])
w = LinearImageProcess()
w.show()
app.exec()
```

If you, instead, want to provide browsing/processing in *both* directions, things get a bit tricky: the problem is that the thread queue might need to change while it's processing because the user has changed browsing direction (or even skipped to another index).

A possible solution is to implement a further queue for the UI that depends on the current index. This results in the UI thread requesting a new process only when a new image has been received from the thread, and then queue the next process request only based on the current index. A benefit of this approach is that it would obviously work even for the simpler "linear" direction used above.

```
class NonLinearImageProcess(QWidget):
    cacheSize = 20
    _currentIndex = -1
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.startButton = QPushButton('Start')

        self.browseWidget = QWidget(enabled=False)
        browseLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.browseWidget)
        browseLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        style = self.style()
        self.beginButton = QToolButton(
            icon=style.standardIcon(style.SP_MediaSkipBackward))
        self.backButton = QToolButton(
            icon=style.standardIcon(style.SP_ArrowLeft))
        self.imageSpin = QSpinBox(keyboardTracking=False)
        self.forwardButton = QToolButton(
            icon=style.standardIcon(style.SP_ArrowRight))
        self.endButton = QToolButton(
            icon=style.standardIcon(style.SP_MediaSkipForward))
        
        browseLayout.addWidget(self.beginButton)
        browseLayout.addWidget(self.backButton)
        browseLayout.addWidget(self.imageSpin)
        browseLayout.addWidget(self.forwardButton)
        browseLayout.addWidget(self.endButton)

        self.view = QLabel()
        self.view.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.view.setFixedSize(600, 600)

        layout.addWidget(self.startButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.browseWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.view, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.fileList = tuple(enumerate(
            QDir(QDir.tempPath()).entryList(['*.jpg', '*.png'])))
        self.imageSpin.setRange(1, len(self.fileList))
        self.imageSpin.setSuffix(' of {}'.format(len(self.fileList)))

        self.cache = {}
        self.loadQueue = []
        self.loader = Loader()
        self.loader.start()
        self.loader.imageReady.connect(self.imageReady)
        self.goToTimer = QTimer(self, singleShot=True, 
            interval=100, timeout=self.goTo)

        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.beginButton.clicked.connect(self.goToStart)
        self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.goToPrevious)
        self.forwardButton.clicked.connect(self.goToNext)
        self.endButton.clicked.connect(self.goToEnd)
        # the lambda is required since valueChanged sends an integer argument
        # that would be used as interval for start()
        self.imageSpin.valueChanged.connect(lambda: self.goToTimer.start())

        self.setMaximumSize(self.sizeHint())

    @pyqtProperty(int)
    def currentIndex(self):
        return self._currentIndex

    @currentIndex.setter
    def currentIndex(self, index):
        if index < 0:
            index = 0
        maxIndex = len(self.fileList) - 1
        if index > maxIndex:
            index = maxIndex
        if self._currentIndex == index:
            return

        self._currentIndex = index
        canGoBack = index > 0
        self.beginButton.setEnabled(canGoBack)
        self.backButton.setEnabled(canGoBack)
        canGoForward = index < maxIndex
        self.forwardButton.setEnabled(canGoForward)
        self.endButton.setEnabled(canGoForward)

    def start(self):
        self.startButton.setEnabled(False)
        if not self.fileList:
            return
        self.currentIndex = 0
        self.loader.process(*self.fileList[0])
        for i, file in self.fileList[1:self.cacheSize // 2]:
            self.loadQueue.append(i)

    def goTo(self, index=None):
        if index is None:
            index = self.imageSpin.value() - 1
        oldIndex = self.currentIndex
        self.currentIndex = index
        if oldIndex == self.currentIndex:
            return

        pm = self.cache.get(index)
        if isinstance(pm, QPixmap):
            self.view.setPixmap(self.cache[index])
            self.browseWidget.setEnabled(True)
            self.imageSpin.setFocus()
            with QSignalBlocker(self.imageSpin):
                self.imageSpin.setValue(index + 1)
        else:
            self.browseWidget.setEnabled(False)

        partCacheSize = self.cacheSize // 2
        start = max(0, index - partCacheSize)
        end = min(index + partCacheSize + 1, len(self.fileList))
        for i in range(start):
            if isinstance(self.cache.get(i), QPixmap):
                self.cache.pop(i)
        for i in range(end, len(self.fileList)):
            if isinstance(self.cache.get(i), QPixmap):
                self.cache.pop(i)
        
        self.loadQueue.clear()
        # try to equally process images from both "edges" of the queue: i.e. if
        # the current index is 30, queue indexes 31, 29, 32, 28, etc.
        for pair in zip_longest(range(index - 1, start - 1, -1), range(index, end)):
            for i in pair:
                if (i is not None and i not in self.cache):
                    self.loadQueue.append(i)
        self.processNextInQueue()

    def processNextInQueue(self):
        if self.loadQueue:
            nextIndex = self.loadQueue.pop(0)
            self.loader.process(*self.fileList[nextIndex])

    def goToStart(self):
        self.goTo(0)

    def goToPrevious(self):
        self.goTo(self.currentIndex - 1)

    def goToNext(self):
        self.goTo(self.currentIndex + 1)

    def goToEnd(self):
        self.goTo(len(self.fileList) - 1)

    def imageReady(self, index, image):
        pm = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self.cache[index] = pm
        if self.currentIndex == index:
            self.view.setPixmap(pm)
            self.browseWidget.setEnabled(True)
            self.imageSpin.setFocus()
            with QSignalBlocker(self.imageSpin):
                self.imageSpin.setValue(index + 1)
        if index in self.loadQueue:
            self.loadQueue.remove(index)
        self.processNextInQueue()
```

Comment: Thanks for your outstanding answer and sorry for the late feedback - not a lot time to write the code theses days unfortunately :-)

You helped a lot, that's what I wanted.

(Btw: For anyone who wants to try the code - if the GUI does not open any pictures check "self.fileList", maybe you have to add the full path to the pictures if the script is not in the temporary folder from the example above (I had to do so).)